# How to make a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, so I've got some troubles with creating queries. 
My task is: To select a description of a product which was selling the most in 1989 with maximum discount.[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2xQ9.png). [Price table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efIlh.png). What I tried to do is

1. Select maximum discount by subtracting list_price - min_price

   ```
   select max(list_price - min_price) from PRICE
   ```
2. Select description

   ```
   select description from product 
   join price on PRODUCT.product_id = PRICE.product_id 
   where start_date = '1989'
   ```

The problem is that I can't make it in one query

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ? Your pics are of SQL Server.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You really should have some sample data (not in a screenshot). You want someone to easily recreate your data to make it easier to answer your question. It's also a good idea to provide table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 1
   product.product_id,
   description,
   max_disc = max(list_price - min_price) 
from PRICE 
join product on product.product_id = PRICE.product_id 
where start_date = '1989'
group by product.product_id, description
order by max_disc desc
```

Comment: This answer looks more correct! It outputs only one description as planned! Sir, could you explain your code. What it does step-by-step? Thank you for your time!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you try like below

```
   select * from 
    (
    select description from product 
    join price 
    on PRODUCT.product_id = PRICE.product_id 
    where start_date = '1989'
    ) t1
    cross join (select max(list_price - min_price) as p from PRICE) t
```

Comment: Thanks brother it works somehow. Could you explain step-by-step how your code works? What it does? Thanks!

Comment: @Kas if it works mark it as accept answer just read a article about cross join rest of the things you did

Answer (score 0):

- `Inner Join` between the two tables using `product_id`, and calculate `ist_price - min_price AS discount`
- Filter out the resultset to carry prices of 1989 only, using `where YEAR(start_date) = 1989`
- Consider the resultset as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and sort it using `discount` value in descending order. Use `Limit 1` to find the product with maximum discount given in the year 1989.

For MySQL, try the following:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM (
      SELECT 
        pt.product_id, 
        pt.description, 
        pe.list_price - pe.min_price AS discount 
      FROM PRODUCT AS pt
      JOIN PRICE AS pe ON pt.product_id = pe.product_id 
      WHERE YEAR(pe.start_date) = 1989 
     ) AS dt 
ORDER BY dt.discount DESC LIMIT 1
```